# How can I pass the current cache instance into a service/controller?

Tags: caching, symfony4

As I understand it right, Symfony 4 has its "own" cache instance. I would like to use it in my controllers and services, but fail to do so.

My `/config/packages/framework.yaml` looks like:

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #default_locale: en
    #csrf_protection: ~
    #http_method_override: true

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY [...]
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: ~

    #esi: ~
    #fragments: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

    cache:
        # Put the unique name of your app here: the prefix seed
        # is used to compute stable namespaces for cache keys.
        # prefix_seed: foobar

        # The app cache caches to the filesystem by default.
        # Other options include:

        # Redis
        #app: cache.adapter.redis
        #default_redis_provider: redis://localhost

        # APCu (not recommended with heavy random-write [...]
        #app: cache.adapter.apcu
```

Got cache related packages in my composer.json:

```
"require": {
        [...]
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.0.6",
        "symfony/cache": "^4.0.6",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0.6",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0.6",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0.6",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^4.0.6",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0.6",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0.6",
        "twig/twig": ">2.4"
    },
```

My current workaround is, that I use a custom Cache instance (Filebased atm). To make it work, I determine the environment and build a path to the cache folder myself:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['env'])) {
    $env = $_SERVER['env'];
} elseif (isset($_ENV['env'])) {
    $env = $_ENV['env'];
} else {
    throw new \Exception('Could not determine environment.');
}

$this->cache = new FilesystemCache('', 0, __DIR__ .'/../../var/cache/'. $env);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for cache services,

```
$ bin/console debug:container | grep cache
 cache.app           Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter
```

And inject it into any controller/service like any other service:

```
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

public function __construct(AdapterInterface $cache)
....
```

(class name in use is little different than in the service list, it is hinted if you try to use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will mark this as solving the question. 
Regardless, I decided to keep my workaround, because i often have to clear my cached items. If i would clear the whole cache, symfony gets unstable. Instead, it remembers all of my cache items to be able to remove them and nothing else.